# how to set error message for each field in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, message

i want to set different error message for each field in the form.This is my controller..

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name','required');
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'कृपया प्रथम नाव भरा','fname'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address','required');
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'कृपया पत्ता भरा','address');
```

but problem is that if validation fails it print only error message for last field.

Comment: hi can you show view code how you are handling errors

Comment: in view i m  printing <?php echo validation_errors();?>

Comment: remove marathi and do in english is that working plz check

Comment: i already tested it with english for one field and then apply on all field with marathi...

Comment: hi can you translate errors messages you are setting

Comment: for 'fname'-> please fill first name field...for 'address'->please fill the address

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it ...first of all autoload form helper and thern in view file

```
 <?php if (form_error('gender'))
 {
    echo "कृपया लिंग निवडा";
 } 
 ;?>
```

where 'gender' is my field name.And I do it for each field in my form.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to the following thing if you use

```
<?php echo validation_errors();?>
```

this will print all error in one place if you want to print each field with its own error then use this

```
<? echo form_input('field_name').br().form_error('field_name') ?>
```

if you are using multi language site then put your all error message in language files

please read form validation doc for complete understanding

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. the OP wants to set multiple error messages for couple of fields have the same validation method.