# Jquery empty field add message beside the field

Tags: php, codeigniter

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login_form").submit(function(event){
    var username = $.trim($("#username").val());
    var password = $.trim($("#password").val());


    if(username.length < 1){
            if(!$("#user_error").length){
            $("#username_error").append("<p id='user_error'>Required</p>");
            }
    }

    if(username.length < 1|| password.length < 1){ 
    $("#username_error").append("<p id='user_error'>Required</p>");
    $("#password_error").append("<p id='pass_error'>Required</p>");
    event.preventDefault();
    }




    });
});
```

View:

```
<? $attr = array( "id" => "login_form"); echo form_open("KGLogin/verify_login",$attr); ?>
        <table id="loginform">
        <tr>
        <th>Log-in</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="username" id='username' placeholder="Username" />
        </td>
        <td id="username_error"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="password" name="password" id='password' placeholder="Password" />
        </td>
        <td id="password_error"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <? echo form_close(); ?>
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? IF i submit it twice without inputting anything, it will continue to append. Im a newbie to jquery, Cant seem to find a simple way to do things, all search results in google directs me to complicated jqueries.

How do i keep the function from stacking the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Ill just put this as an answer, so no one would suggest.

```
<?if(form_error('username'))echo "required";;?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509180/how-to-set-error-message-for-each-field-in-codeigniter-php

Comment: I tried that, it seems not to work for me. Thanks. Ill just keep trying until i get whats wrong.

Comment: I think you didnt autoload something in autoload file

Comment: I edited my question, could you check it out, i decided to use jquery since form validation is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in autoload file.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','array','html','form');
```

Then try this in view file

```
<?php if (form_error('your field name'))
 {
echo "required";
} 
;?>
```